# Recycler view is not rendering when width & height are set to 0dp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple layout, which contains a `text view`, `ImageView`, and a `recycler view`, If i set recycler's view width & height to 0dp, and connects its constraint to parent, it does not render the recycler view.

But if i define height in numbers then it works fine, and renders `recyclerview`

This is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".activities.MyActivityV2">

    <include layout="@layout/content_more_activity" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Inner Layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MyActivityV2"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_more">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        android:text="MORE"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView23"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMoreItems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView23" />
```

**Class File**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        init();
        generateDataForRecyclerView();
        initRecyclerView();
    }



    private void init() {

        rvMoreItems= findViewById(R.id.rvMoreItems);

    }


     private void generateDataForRecyclerView() {

        MoreDataClass moreDataClass= new MoreDataClass();
        moreDataClass.setLabel("AAA");
        moreDataClass.setHeaderItem(true);
        dataList.add(moreDataClass);

        dataList.add(moreDataClass);
}


    private void initRecyclerView() {

        MoreAdapter moreAdapter= new MoreAdapter(this);
        moreAdapter.setData(dataList);
        rvMoreItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvMoreItems.setAdapter(moreAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: Can you also provide java/kotlin code where you're using RecyclerView

Comment: try setting unique background to recyclerview and check if its displaying or not

Comment: @Yoric: I have added class file. Please check

Comment: @Ankit : No background color is also not visible

Comment: Change height with "wrap_content" or remove this line:
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"

Comment: @Kirmani88 I had to add missing code by myself just to be able to build project with your sample, also replaced CoordinatorLayout, ConstraintLayout and RecyclerView with versions from androidx package and everything works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Update this function check below.

```
 private void initRecyclerView() {

        MoreAdapter moreAdapter= new MoreAdapter(this);
        rvMoreItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvMoreItems.setAdapter(moreAdapter);
        moreAdapter.setData(dataList);

    }
```